# Error: function timed out, ensure the callback is executed within 5000 milliseconds

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber, wait

I'm using Protractor 5.1.2, npm 5.6.0
It's failing when It tries to click on Login button.
I'm getting  "Error: function timed out, ensure the callback is executed within 5000 milliseconds" I cannot find where can I change these 5000 milliseconds

**homepage.step.ts**

```
import { AppPage } from '../../pageobjects/app';
import { Homepage } from '../../pageobjects/homepage';
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
const { Before } = require('cucumber');
const { Given } = require("cucumber");
const { When } = require("cucumber");
const { Then } = require("cucumber");
const { setDefaultTimeout } = require ("cucumber");
const chai = require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised"));
const expect = chai.expect;
let page: AppPage;
let homepage: Homepage;

Before(() => {
page = new AppPage();
homepage = new Homepage();
});

Given('I am on the login page', function () {
      page.navigateTo();
});

When('I fill in teller with {string}', function (string) {

homepage.teller.sendKeys(string);

});

When('I fill in pin with {string}', function (string) {

homepage.pin.sendKeys(string);

});

When('I press Login', function (string) {

homepage.loginButton.click();

});

Then('I should see the {string}', function (string) {

expect(homepage.sideBar).to.eventually.equal(string);

});
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

specs: [
    './e2e/features/*.feature'
],

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
},
directConnect: true,
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'e2e/features/step_definitions/*.step.ts',
    tags: [], // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    strict: true, // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    //format: ["pretty"],            // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    'dry-run': false, // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    compiler: [] // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
},

onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json',
    });
},
```

};

**PO**

```
import { by,ProtractorBy, element } from "protractor";
export class Homepage {

sideMenu = element(by.css('.sidebar-nav'));
statusBar = element(by.css('.status-bar-content'));
container = element(by.css('.container-fluid'));
teller = element (by.css('[formcontrolname=user_id]'));
pin= element (by.css('[formcontrolname=pin]'));
loginButton = element(by.buttonText('Login'));
sideBar= element(by.className('.sidebar'));
activeNav = element (by.css('.nav-link active'));
}
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
Failures:

1) Scenario: login with valid credentials # e2e\features\login.feature:12
√ Before # e2e\features\step_definitions\homepage.step.ts:15
√ Before # e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:15
√ Given I am on the login page # 
e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:35
√ When I fill in teller with "1" # 
e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:41
√ When I fill in pin with "1" # 
e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:47
× When I press Login # e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:53
   Error: function timed out, ensure the callback is executed within 5000 
   milliseconds
   at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\ui- 
   terminal\node_modules\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.js:61:18)
   at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
   at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
   at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
- When I should see the "sidebar" # 
e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:61
- Then I should see the home menue option active # 
e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:74
```

Comment: Could you add your code so that we have a way to recreate the error? Please copy pasta the actual code, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Ben, here is the code.
import { AppPage } from '../../pageobjects/app';
import { Homepage } from '../../pageobjects/homepage';
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
const { Before } = require('cucumber');
const { Given } = require("cucumber");
const { When } = require("cucumber");
const { Then } = require("cucumber");
const { setDefaultTimeout } = require ("cucumber");
const chai = require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised"));
const expect = chai.expect;
let page: AppPage;
let homepage: Homepage;

Comment: Before(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
    homepage = new Homepage();
});
Given('I am on the login page', function () {
          
    page.navigateTo();

    });

When('I fill in teller with {string}', function (string) {
     
    homepage.teller.sendKeys(string);
          
    });

When('I fill in pin with {string}', function (string) {
    
    homepage.pin.sendKeys(string);

    });

When('I press Login', function (string) {
     
    homepage.loginButton.click();
    
    });

Comment: And the error: 
1) Scenario: login with valid credentials 
√ Given I am on the login 
√ When I fill in teller with "1" 
√ When I fill in pin with "1"    
× When I press Login # e2e\features\step_definitions\login.step.ts:53
       Error: function timed out, ensure the callback is executed within 5000 milliseconds
           at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\ui-terminal\node_modules\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.js:61:18)
           at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
           at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
           at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. It is near impossible to read it over multiple comments

Comment: sorry! there it is

Answer (score 1):

The error said the step definition function timeout, so you should fix it from cucumber side.

Add bellow timeout.js:

```
// timeout.js
var { setDefaultTimeout } = require("cucumber");

setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000); 
// this timeout value is global setting impact all step definition function,
// thus it doesn't means the value is more large more better.
```

Then includes it in `cucumberOpts.require`:

```
cucumberOpts: {   
   require: ["supports/timeout.js", ...]
```

If you have some special step need more time than the global value, you can specify other timeout value for such step:

```
Given(/^a slow step$/, {timeout: 90 * 1000}, function() {
  // Does some slow browser/filesystem/network actions
});
```

Yon can find more detail from [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/support_files/timeouts.md)

Comment: When I set the setDefaultTimeout, it ended up with all the tests ''undefined" (I don't know why). But it worked out by adding the timeout to the step. Thank you yong!